# There is an offline software to test a website in different browsers?

Tags: testing, web, cross-browser, offlineapps

I'm looking for an *offline software* that can speed up the testing of a website in different browsers.

Yes, I can install Opera, Firefox, Chrome, IE and Safari and test in each one, but this slow down the process because there are a lot of changes to be done in the website I am working and each change must be tested in all browsers.

More specifically, I am looking for something similar to [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage), but for different browsers. I'm not interested in online services (there are a lot), but offline.

So, someone knows something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find the Selenium tool [ http://seleniumhq.org/ ] very useful for such needs:

- there are drivers for almost all modern and not-so-modern browsers: firefox, IE, Opera, Chrome, Safari..
- scales quite well through the webdriver thing (remote control execution of tests on many different hosts), and
- is well established: there are many resources available around to develop and deploy it.

Main drawback, as for my own experience: the learning curve is somewhat tough.

There is also a nice test management tool especially targeted at Selenium: [Bromine](http://www.brominefoundation.org) (disclaimer: I did not yet use Bromine, but saw great comments on it).

Regards,

--
boris

Answer (score 2):

<strike>[**Adobe BrowserLab**](https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html) for Desktop Browsers (Free)</strike> As noted in the comments, this has been discontinued. But they [**recommend**](http://blogs.adobe.com/browserlab/2013/03/13/browserlab-is-shutting-down-on-march-13-2013/) [**Sauce labs**](https://saucelabs.com/), and [**Browser Stack**](https://www.browserstack.com/) instead.

Adobe Edge Inspect aka [**Shadow**](http://html.adobe.com/edge/inspect/) is also available and does all the above quite well. It is primarily for Mobile Browser testing and debugging.

Microsoft's Expression Suite also has its own Cross-Browser Testing utility, called [**Expression Web Super-Preview**](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd565874.aspx).

In Microsoft's words,

> You can view browser renderings side-by-side horizontally or
>   vertically, or overlay them to identify differences. You can use
>   rulers and guides to measure and highlight visual problems. You can
>   zoom in and out of a page and see all the browser renderings update in
>   tandem.

Comment: Adobe Browser lab is shut down from March 2013.

Answer (score 1):

You can try BrowseEmAll (http://www.browseemall.com) which is a desktop application for windows (and sadly windows online).

Still it contains all major browsers and simulators for iOS and Android which should make the testing easier than switching between different browsers manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you like groovy, then try Spock. 
I've experimented with Spock and Gem for BDD tests.